# Влияние на производительность

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Вопрос скорее для профи, на удовлетворение моей любопытности.
Допустим у нас есть:

```html
<div class="lvl-1">
  <h1 class="tit">TEST</h1>
  <p class="con">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea maiores impedit magni <a href="#" class="url-con">animi</a> quos fugit ex odit non tenetur, doloribus doloremque cum accusamus, nisi eius!</p>
</div>
```

и допустим я хочу обратится через css к классу `.url-con`
я это могу сделать разными способами: `.url-con` или `.lvl-1 > .con > .url-con` или `.con > .url-con`... и т.д.
Зависит ли способ обращения к элементам на скорость обработки страницы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зависит, но разница настолько ничтожна, что никто ее не заметит, даже на старом по нынешним меркам железе.

Браузер обрабатывает селекторы, начиная с конца. В случае с `.url-con` - он найдет все ноды с таким классом, и применит к ним стили.

В случае с `.con > .url-con` браузер точно так же, как в первом случае, найдет все ноды с классом `.url-con`, а потом среди них оставит только те, у которых есть предок с классом `.con`. И применит к ним стили.

В случае с `.lvl-1 > .con > .url-con`:

- Найдет все ноды с классом `.url-con`;
- Из них оставит только ноды с предком с классом `.con`;
- Из них оставит только ноды с предком с классом `.lvl-1`;
- И применит к ним стили.

Comment: Большое спасибо)))